# Entity Framework + SQL Server - Slow joining operation?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using C# and Entity Framework to communicate with a SQL Server database in which I have 2 tables that I need information from. The first table (the dimension table) represent certain counters, and holds information such as: counter ID (primary key), counter type, machine it's relating to. The second table (the fact table), holds counter data such as data ID (primary key), counter ID (foreign key, links to the dimension table), date and value.

I use Entity Framework to work with those tables, and I used Visual Studio's tool to link it all together. I designed it in Visual Studio so it is possible to get counter type details from the counter data class like this -- `CounterData.CounterDetail.CounterType`. Entity Framework takes care of this joining (at least I hope it does).

Now, as input, I get the machine name and the counter type(s). I need to print all the counter data (all the facts) for that particular counter type(s) (dimension(s)). I wrote this kind of code (assuming that db is my Entity Framework object):

```
db.CounterDatas.Where(x => (x.CounterDetail.MachineID == input_machine) && 
input_counter_types.Contains(x.CounterDetail.CounterType)).Select(x => x).GroupBy(x => x.CounterDetail);
```

Then I iterate the groups using foreach, and I also iterate over each group.
However, this is incredibly slow. The database tables are massive (the fact table is over 40 million rows), but manually executing an SQL query I wrote on my own executes in a blink. Entity Framework is very slow about it, though.

At first, I thought that

```
input_counter_types.Contains(x.CounterDetail.CounterType)
```

part slows it down a lot, but after taking a look at the SQL query IntelliSense reported, Entity Framework actually expands that `input_counter_types` part into something like

```
CounterType IN ('A', 'B', 'C', ...)
```

where A, B, C, ... are the constants stored in the hash set `input_counter_types`, and that should actually execute quickly without a problem, right?

I also read somewhere on Stack Overflow that the problem with these LINQ queries sometimes is that LINQ loads too many rows (much more than needed) into local memory and then filters data locally. This is undesired behavior here, I want the SQL Server to do the filtering work, I just want the filtered data locally.

Is it possible to do? I will have similar code in different parts of the project (with varying complexity) and I prefer to let Entity Framework do all the database work. Perhaps it's not the best decision?

Comment: Instead of using db.CounterDatas, why don't you just query off the CounterDetails directly?  That is your fact table, right?  That may have something to do with it.  Also, paste in your table definitions and the query that's being generated.  We're left guessing here.

Comment: Not quite, sorry about being confusing. db.CounterDatas are my facts, dbCounterDetails are my dimensions. Basically, I need to output all the facts corresponding to the given dimensions (the dimensions asked are stored in the aformentioned HashSet).

No code is provided because I have no access to it until tomorrow, but this is pretty much exactly what I use. Also, the queries that EF uses are extremely long and confusing, I am not sure if they would be helpful. I will post them tomorrow if nobody helps by then. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.
For anyone who wants to know, I solved it by flipping my selection logic.
Instead of using `Where` with `x.CounterDetail`-using expressions, I used `Where` with `x.CounterDatas`-using expression while selecting detail entities, instead of data entities. In the end, I do the same thing (though without a `GroupBy`), but it significantly sped everything up.